# jquery check/uncheck event trigger

Tags: jquery

I have this code that works half way through

```
jQuery('#checkbox').click(function () {
   jQuery('.cssBox').animate({height:'+=50px'}, 500);
   jQuery('#extra').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Right now, the cssbox gets enlarged when the checkbox is checked but when unchecked the cssbox keeps on getting bigger. How can I fix it so that when unchecked, it gets back to the original size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
jQuery('#checkbox').click(function () {
   jQuery('.cssBox').animate({height: ((this.checked)?'+=50px':'-=50px')}, 500);
   jQuery('#extra').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much works like a dream :) ... simple solutions are always the best.

Comment: @Splash Also use `change` instead of `click` as Brad suggested http://stackoverflow.com/a/10418698/297641.

Answer (score 1):

Use `change` instead of `click` (otherwise tabbing through and using space bar will bypass your code). Also, apply your animation based on the `checked` state:

```
jQuery('#checkbox').change(function(){
  jQuery('.cssBox').animate({
    height: this.checked   // is it checked?
      ? '+=50px'              // yes, increase by 50px
      : '-=50px'              // no, decrease by 50px
  },500);
  jQuery('#extra').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: hmm, didn't think about the tab/space combination ... thanks. Also, using your suggestion breaks my other jquery functions but using Vega's suggestion and just replacing the click with the change works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var isSmall=true;
    $('#checkbox').click(function () {
        if(isSmall)
        {
           $('.cssBox').animate({height:'+=50px'}, 500);
        }
        else            
        {
           $('.cssBox').animate({height:'-=50px'}, 500);
        }
       isSmall=!isSmall;
    });        
});​
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/2nU7b/4/

Comment: Globals huh? This would've been better even if you just used `.data` instead of globals (well, globals in the context of an anonymous function)

Comment: @BradChristie That is not global, it is inside closure.

Comment: @Vega: That's why I mentioned context in parenthesis. It's still outside of the event block where, which is what I was getting at.